# Issues with Django authentication

Tags: django, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I have a website that is being used by various corporate employees. Just today I have a user saying that everytime they login (even with correct username and password), they get an error saying they have to login to view the page. Basically, they type the right username/password and get forwarded to the home page, but that controller has a login required decorator which rejects them and they get sent back to the login screen. The user tried in IE10 and Google Chrome web browsers.

I have not been able to replicate this issue anywhere and unfortunately, i'm in no position to really ask this user for more information for debugging purposes :(. Has anybody seen this before??

I tried googling this, and i'm seeing issues with Django for IE but nothing with Chrome. Is there anything else that could be happening?

I'm using nginx+uwsgi on the server if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 1):

Without more information this is pretty much impossible to solve.

Because no one else is having the problem and you can't reproduce it, I'm inclined to believe it's user error.

Have them clear their cache/cookies (The fact that it's multi-browser is troubling though), see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Best guess so far without more information: The user has cookies disabled. I think Django auth relies on cookies.